# fetch request at express root router from react not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, openshift

I am trying to call the express root router ('/') from fetch api in react in production mode but it doesn't work.

I am using common server as I am using the react views as static files and renderning like this:

```
if(process.env.NODE_ENV == 'production'){
    app.use(express.static(`${__dirname}/client/build`));
    app.get('*', (req, res) => {
        res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'/client/build/index.html'));
      });
    }
```

Also, i have already tried using the production hostname as the route in fetch but that doesn't work for me as I am using a proxy.

The complete story is that I am trying to get some tokens that I get from openshift oauth-proxy authentication. There are two containers, one for proxy and another for my web app. When the user is authenticated, proxy sends a token to 'localhost:8080' (which is my web app).

I am handling it this way,

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    if (req.headers !== undefined && req.headers['x-forwarded-access-token'] !== undefined && req.headers['x-forwarded-user'] != undefined) {

        userDetails.accessToken = req.headers['x-forwarded-access-token'];
        userDetails.username = req.headers['x-forwarded-user'];

        req.session.token = userDetails.accessToken;
        req.session.username = userDetails.username;

        res.send({ accessToken: userDetails.accessToken, username: userDetails.username});
    }  
});
```

But when I call the above router from fetch api from react, i don't get the response. The app crashes.

When I am running it on development environment, I am running both on different servers, and when i write it completely, like '`fetch('http://localhost:3001')`'
then it works.

I want it to work in production as well. Any help?

**More details**

The overall flow is, that I have deployed my react app on openshift. I am using oauth-proxy to authenticate the user and then land onto my react app once proxy sends me the authentication token in the react app.

There are two containers, proxy and web-app, inside the proxy-app pod. When i go to the route of the pod, it takes me to the keycloak login page where i enter my credentials, once authenticated, proxy send the auth-token in the headers to it's sidecar container which is my web-app (running on localhost:8080 inside the pod.)  Proxy sends the headers to the `localhost:8080/` (webapp) which is the root of the web app. Now here, i have to make a fetch request from client to this route and get the token(which i am not able to since it doesn't work this way probably because i am using a proxy which is running on different host than my web app). But when i make request on other routes like ('/api/xyz'), it works like charm. There is something with the root route and proxy that is creating the issue.

Comment: I am handling cors using npm cors package in my express server. app.use(cors());

Comment: Sorry, I read that a bit too hastily. `app crashes` is too vague, show us errors.  Can it be your proxy that is just not forwarding the headers?

Comment: The proxy is passing the headers, but it passes the headers on root ('/'). I want to get those headers from there and then send those tokens when my browser makes a request on root router ('/') which i am doing from fetch API.

Comment: So basically there are two requests: a) Your proxy sends a request to your webapp with the token and b) Your react app makes a request for this information. I'm a little confused as you have shown only one route which accepts the token from the proxy and immediately responds with the token. If you hit this route from your react app, your if condition will probably fail (because of missing headers) and your middleware does not terminate the request (by sending response, for example) nor does it call `next`. This is probably what is causing your app to hang/not respond/crash

Comment: then how do i call that api from client?

Comment: i had created this app in basic javascript and ejs before and i used to render('index', {token: '<token>'}), and then save that token in html element and then use that token further. But in react how do i get the token?

Comment: That is relatively simple in one route you a) Receive the token from your proxy and store it on the session (I have a question here that I'll come back to) b) In a separate route which you hit from react, send the token stored in the session to the client using `res.json`.  The problem I see here is that storing on the session may not work if the request is from the proxy and does not carry the session cookie of the user (the proxy is seen as a new user). If you are clear on if the session is preserved when the token request comes through from the proxy - this should be easy to do.

Comment: You can also render your token down with your react file like in your eariler approach. Just start using index.html of your react app as an ejs template with the token in the DOM as a dynamic item. You can then look it up from the DOM in your `componentDidMount` lifecycle method of your root component of your react app

Comment: should i do this?  res.render(path.join(__dirname + '/client/build/index.html'), { accessToken: '<token>' }); or change the extension of the index.html in react to index.ejs also

Comment: My recommendation would be to stick to express standards - Create a views directory, register your views folder, set your view engine, move your index.html to your views folder and change the extension. - But I'm pretty sure you could use your `index.html` directly as your template.

Comment: would i be able to do that in production as well where i use the static html files which get created in build directory? Little new to react and I am using create-react-app boiler plate. It's getting little confusing now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked when I added cors in my react code. I had it in my server code but not on react.

```
fetch('/auth', {
  credentials: 'include',
  mode: 'cors'
})
```